# Navigation bar alignment <ul>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to align the  bar in the middle of nav bar vertically. I set align-items: center for  bar but it only aligns the sign in button. As you can see, it's slightly above the middle position.

```css
nav a{
color:white;
}
nav{
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: brown;

}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;

}
nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" >
            <nav class="d-flex flex-row">
                <h1 class="sling"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mb-0` on the UL to clear the bottom margin.

```
    <nav class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <h1 class="sling"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
        <ul class="mb-0">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
    </nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Fa33cYUN52

Answer (score 2):

You need to zero the bottom `margin` of `nav ul`. The margin exists due to default browser styles.

```css
nav a {
  color: white;
}

nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: brown;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* <-- + Added */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="d-flex flex-row">
    <h1 class="sling"><a href="index.html">Sling</a></h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="signin">Sign in</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Others are all saying to clear out the margin bottom. How about `align-items: baseline;` instead of center:

```
nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/3nzgecrt/4/

[image]